# Using CSS3 Pseudo elements to Format a Chart

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am constructing an ancestor chart using an unordered list, but I am having trouble getting it to look right on screen. I started off using code from [CSS3 Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/index.php/walkthrough/css3-family-tree), which, despite the name, produces something which is an organisation chart rather than a family tree.

For the purpose of testing, I have HTML and CSS like this:

```css
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.tree li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Self</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Father</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grandfather</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grandmother</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mother</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grandfather</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grandmother</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS is lifted almost directly from CSS3 Family Tree.

This produces a chart that looks like this

[image: Ancestor chart]

but I need it to be inverted, with "Self"at the bottom and the earliest generation at the top.

I can get the boxes inverted by inverting the list structure but I can't find a way to modify the CSS the get the connectors to look right.

[image: Inverted tree]

Is there a way to modify the ::before and ::after pseudo elements to get what I want? Or am I going about it in completely the wrong way?

(It would also be acceptable to put "Self" on the left and the earliest generation on the right if that would work better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-arrange the `HTML`, and with some `css` tweaks (i.e. swap top & bottom paddings, swap top & bottom positions and change border-radius to match the new arrangement) it works:

```css
.tree ul {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.tree li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px 20px 5px;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grandfather</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Grandmother</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#">Father</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grandfather</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Grandmother</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#">Mother</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#">Self</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q02v3up/1/) that contains the (reversed) original tree from the code player website.

Comment: That was how I intended to re-arrange the HTML. It was the CSS pseudo-elements that were beating me. Thanks for the assistance with that. It is truly appreciated.